# @media запросы. Некорректное отображение блока

Tags: css, html5, media-queries

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне необходимо, чтобы блок скрывался при ширине экрана меньше или равен 767px. А при ширине экрана больше или равен 768px появлялся. Но мой код почему-то не срабатывает.
Мой код:

```css
.promo_text_easy {
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: orange;
}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .promo_text_easy {
        display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>интенсив</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="promo_text_easy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Какой браузер вы используете? Так как у меня всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Я использую Opera и у меня всё в порядке.
Попробуй обновить через Ctrl + F5 для обновления страницы вместе с кэшем. Проверь сохранения файла и из той ли директории ты запустил сайт

Если не помогло - используй `display: none !important;`